# vuetify child component property

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to wrap a vuetify component into another one and select which property is configured from the parent.

I.e.Child component myToolbar

```
<template>
   <v-toolbar app fixed></..>
</templare>
```

in parent I would like to configure the fact that the child uses a black, flat attribute like:

```
<my-toolbar black flat>...</my-toolbar>
```

How can I know from my child component which attributes where passed by the parent and enable them on the v-toolbar ?

I seem to be stuck with the fact that those are booleans so dark=true does not seem to work.

Any help would be welcome,

Thanks

Pat

Comment: <my-toolbar black flat> is the short way to write <my-toolbar :black="isBlack" :flat="isFlat"> so you can controll the props in this variables if I could understand your problem

Comment: Which child component would you like to inherit those properties?

Comment: Matheus, I tried to put <v-toolbar app fixed :black="isBlack"> and define isBlack in the data section as true/false/undefined, but it won't consider the value. It doesn't give an error but the black property is never applied as in <v-toolbar app fixed black>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on @Prashant - here is an example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/jll61on13

**Topbar.vue**

```
<template>
  <v-toolbar v-bind="$attrs">
    <slot/>
  </v-toolbar>
</template>
```

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <!-- ------------------------------------- -->
    <!-- app-topbar is the custom v-toolbar -->
    <!-- ------------------------------------- -->
    <br>Example 1
    <app-topbar color="primary"></app-topbar>
    <!-- -------------------------------------------- -->
    <br>
    <span>
      Example 2 - using
      <code>slot</code>
    </span>
    <!-- ------------------------------------- -->
    <!-- app-topbar is the custom v-toolbar -->
    <!-- ------------------------------------- -->
    <app-topbar color="primary">
      <v-toolbar-side-icon></v-toolbar-side-icon>
      <v-toolbar-title class="headline text-uppercase">
        <span>v u e</span>
        <span class="font-weight-light">. j s</span>
      </v-toolbar-title>
    </app-topbar>
    <!-- -------------------------------------------- -->
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
import Topbar from "./components/Topbar.vue";
export default {
  components: {
    appTopbar: Topbar
  },
  data() {
    return {};
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass along all the attributes passed to your component to the Vuetify component using `v-bind="$attrs"`

In your component template

```
<template>
   <v-toolbar v-bind="$attrs" app fixed></..>
</template>
```